# How to have multiple versions of external maven dependencies with Bazel?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-java

I am currently using [rules_jvm_external](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external) in order to use external maven dependencies with Bazel. My use-case is to do a major upgrade of a dependency to do a PoC project. What is the best way to get the dependency just for my PoC project.

From the documentation, one option for such a case is to have [multiple maven_install.json files](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external#multiple-maven_installjson-files). However, this doesn't seem feasible for everyone as:

1. We would need to have a looot of maven_install.json files for each PoC.
2. Adds complexity to the developers having to learn more of Bazel (something we want to try to avoid as we want to keep it as simple as we can).